# $emit causing memory leak - Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have two components. A parent and a child. The parent loads the child based on `v-if`. Then the child sends an event through `$emit` to tell the parent to remove the child.

So simply put.

PARENT:

```
data() {
    return {
        show: false
    }
},
// template: 
<div>
    <div @click="show = !show">Toggle</div>
    <child-component
        v-if="show"
        @close="show = false"
   />
</div>
```

CHILD:

```
template: 
<div>
    Some Content
    <div @click="$emit('close')">Close</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when `$emit('close')` is fired, the child is removed from the DOM but the component is not cleared from memory.

If the parent removes the child using the `toggle` button, it does clear the child from memory.

I have also tried using `Vuex store` and `$root.data` but this also causes a memory leak.

In other words, it seems that if the child signals to the parent that it should be removed, it is kept in memory. However, if the parent removes the child directly (without any signal from the child) it's removed from memory...

Any ideas why this happens and what I should do to prevent this memory leak? It's necessary that the child signal it's removal.

[EDIT] - DEMO IN CODE PEN.
https://codepen.io/tomshort5/pen/BaBLXvb

### Memory snapshots

This is best visible by making memory snapshots after certain actions. When the page loads, we have a single Vue instance.
[image: On page load]

After clicking toggle, a VueComponent is created as expected.
[image: After clicking "toggle"]

After triggering the child to be removed through an event, the VueComponent is not removed from memory. When comparing it to clicking "Toggle" again, it does show the component getting removed from memory.
[image: After clicking "Close me"]

Comment: What makes you think there's a memory leak?

Comment: `component is not cleared from memory` how are you identifying for memory leak?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with the example you gave. It correctly shows the component calling its destroyed lifecycle hook. https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-ptpxc?fontsize=14 Obviously it will only clear the memory when the GC is run, but the memory is clear from that point on.

Comment: I have created a codepen and can reproduce here: https://codepen.io/tomshort5/pen/BaBLXvb

In the developer console, memory tab. Take snapshots and filter by "Vue"

Comment: I have added some screenshots to the bottom of the question.

Comment: That's quite odd. The short answer is, for some reason it is still in the first component's $children list. The long answer is: Why?!

Comment: This is a serious rabbit hole. I think my earlier conclusion that it did stick in $children is false, because I am unable to get that situation anymore. Perhaps I just viewed the wrong snapshot? https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXrgP.png shows that it is still being refered from a reactiveGetter, probably as `obj` passed to `defineReactive$$1` on line 1014, being used in line 1039. Which getter? Good question. If I read it right, it would need to be on that particular VueComponent, but it has no internal state. The only thing that would be reactive is `show` on the parent.

Comment: The v-if is parsed on creation of the parent node, which adds an entry to a list of if conditions with a reference to `show`, but at that point VueComponent does not exist yet. I am not sure how you would end up with a floating reference to that VueComponent from that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a partial explanation.

It seems that something is holding onto a reference to the last DOM node that was clicked. So if you click on `Close` it will grab hold of a reference to that text node. The text node's parent is the `<div>` and the `<div>` has a click listener pointing back to the Vue component. The component itself has been destroyed, it just can't be GCed.

If instead you click on `Toggle` it retains a reference to the `Toggle` text node. As that node is in a different section of the DOM tree it doesn't retain any reference to the element with the click listener. The Vue component is successfully GCed.

I haven't been able to establish precisely what retains this reference to the last clicked node. The heap snapshot isn't particularly helpful. It just shows `InternalNode` connecting `window` to the relevant text node.

I did put together a page to explore this without Vue. My experiments suggested that retaining a reference to the last clicked node is something that occurs even when Vue is not on the page.

The memory leak here is only very temporary. Clicking one more time, anywhere on the page, seems to be enough to fix it. Consistent with my theory, that updates the 'last clicked node' reference, allowing the detached DOM nodes to be GCed and the Vue component with it.