# Input event causing memory leak - Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, memory-leaks

So, earlier this week I posted a question about a memory leak issue relating to `$emit`: [$emit causing memory leak - Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57578842/emit-causing-memory-leak-vue-js)

The answer there was that after closing the component, if you clicked anywhere on the page, the garbage cleaner would clear it.

However, now I have found another memory leak scenario where the garbage cleaner does not remove the component, ever. It relates to having a `text input element` and triggering an `@input` event whenever text is entered.

```js
const Child = {
    methods: {
      randomMethod() {
        //do nothing
      }
    },
    template: `
      <div>
        Child Component!
        <input @input="randomMethod" />
        <div @click="$emit('close')">Close me</div>
      </div>
    `
}

new Vue({
   el: "#app",
  components: {
    Child
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      show: false
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <div @click="show = !show">Toggle</div>
      <Child
        v-if="show"
        @close="show = false"
      />
    </div>
  `
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

I have a codepen for you to test out: https://codepen.io/tomshort5/pen/bGbgXym

Here is a demonstration:

### Memory snapshots

Page first load, no child component loaded yet.
[image: Page first load snapshot.]
Load the child component by clicking "Toggle" and enter some text into the input field.
[image: Load child]
Close the child by clicking "Toggle again. Then click anywhere on the page. See that the component is still in memory.
[image: Close child]
Repeat steps 2 and 3, and see that the child component is stacking up in memory
[image: Repeat]

Comment: I'm not Vue expert but it seems that the reference to the component is in randomMethod closure. You can try to null that property in beforeDestroy.